# Javascript multilevel object spread operator

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects, I want all data out from all objects into multiple arrays

```js
const obj = [
  {
    school: {
      name: 'abc',
      students: [
        {
          class: 'A',
          name: 'jhon',
        },
        {
          class: 'B',
          name: 'Doe',
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    school: {
      name: 'XYZ',
      students: [
        {
          class: 'C',
          name: 'Cena',
        },
        {
          class: 'B',
          name: 'Big show',
        },
      ],
    },
  },
];
```

I want result something like

```
[ ["abc", "xyz"], ["A", "B", "C", "B"], ["jhon", "Doe", "Cena", "Big show"]]
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: It depends a lot on how consistent the structure of your array elements are. Will the items in your array always be objects that contain only a `school` object, which will always contain only a `name` and an array of `student`s, which will always contain only a `class` and a `name`?

Comment: structure is consistent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of `reduce` and take `Object.values` of it. While traversing the student array you can take `Object.entries` of Object. Here is a working example:

```js
var obj = [ { school: { name: 'abc', students: [ { class: 'A', name: 'jhon', }, { class: 'B', name: 'Doe', }, ], }, }, { school: { name: 'XYZ', students: [ { class: 'C', name: 'Cena', }, { class: 'B', name: 'Big show', }, ], }, }];

var result = Object.values(obj.reduce((acc, {school})=>{
    acc['schoolname'] = [...(acc['schoolname'] || []), school.name];
    school.students.forEach(s=>{
        Object.entries(s).forEach(([k,v])=>{
        acc[k] = [...(acc[k] || []), v];
    });
   });
  return acc;
},{}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Even though this is already answered, I want to share my approach.

It you are able to add a dependency, [JSONata](https://jsonata.org) is well worth, and it can be used not only to query but also to transform objects with fairly simple queries, that most of the time are way easier to read and understand than regular reducers or maps.

Using JSONata your code will look like this:

```
jsonata('[ [ $.school.name], [ $.school.students.class ], [ $.school.students.name ] ]').evaluate(obj);
```

https://try.jsonata.org/zqqQNjYmx

Comment: Unique answer than others, `jsonata` good plugin, but its `802 kB` in size. I have only one type of data that I am asked in the question. Thanks for your solution

Comment: FWIW, minified and compressed it is only 22 KB. You can see verify this by opening your network inspector on try.jsonata.org and inspecting the request for jsonata.min.js

Answer (score 1):

Using the builtin Array methods.

```js
schoolNames =obj.map(function(school){return school.school.name})
students = obj.map(function(school){return school.school.students}).flat()
studentNames = students.map(function(student){return student.name})
studentClass = students.map(function(student){return student.class})
```

Comment: Nice, I have lots of data in the consistent structure, your code works and gives appropriate data but you know the `heap` is going to be increased as multiple variables are created and extra `CPU` used, but Thanks for your solution

Comment: Facts, I wrote it to Show the data transforms, You could do it without assigning the variables, and chaining.. You can also Just Reduce or write custom functions.. 

My intent was to give the ability to reuse the needed objects.